# Is it possible to create hidden pages in ruby on rails to tor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create hidden pages in ruby on rails to tor (domain with a .onion tip)? Does this provide some privacy for users?

Comment: You'd get better answers from Stack Exchange's [Information Security community](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Sure is possible. You'd just need to make sure your server is proxied to connect to the TOR network. Hell, there's even a Heroku buildpack! https://github.com/apg/heroku-buildpack-tor